# metric spaces, $B_r(x)=B_s(y)$, is $y=x$ and $r=s$?

Tags: metric-spaces

Let if  $B_r(x)$=$B_s(y)$ for some $x$,$y$ in metric space $M$ and $r$,$s$ $\in$ $R$.
Is  true $x=y$? Is true $r=s$?

Answer (score 2):

No. For example:

$$X = \{ 1,2\}\\
d(x,y) = 0 \text{ if $x=y$, 1 otherwise}\\
x = 1, y= 2, r=16, s=26$$

Comment: This makes me wonder if it is true in general for non-discrete spaces. Can you think of a counter example?

Comment: It is true for normed vectorial spaces.

Comment: Yeah that's definitely the case. Good point.

Comment: What? $B_1(x)=\{x\}$, and $B_2(y)=\{x,y\}$ here, so it's not a counterexample (surely we're working with open balls?) It works however if you take $r=42$, $s=9001$. Also, you have a typo in your def: you want $x \neq y$, not $x = y$.

Comment: I considered closed balls. simply take 2 and 3 in the case of open balls :) and thank you for the more serious mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Another counterexample. Take any bounded metric space of diamter $r$. Any ball of radius greater than $\frac{r}{2}$ will cover the entire space and so all such balls are equal no matter their center.

Comment: this is actually the same idea ;)

Comment: @mookid I agree, though I think my answer possibly has more explanatory power. It's also then not hard to imagine examples where you don't need to cover the entire space or even use bounded spaces, such as $X=[0,\infty)$ and the balls $B_1(0)$ and $B_{3/4}(\frac{1}{4})$.

Comment: I agree. {} {} {

Comment: Building on your idea, a similar thing can happen if the space is disconnected, but it may be that only a limited range of radii and centers will yield equal balls. Consider $X=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$.